# Powershell HTML Export is not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, powershell, export

I have another interesting mystery for you to solve.

**Situation**

I basicly use a PowerShell script to generate HTML pages. A meanigful example for this Powershell script would be as following: (Please note this is not the real complete code, but to understand the problem it should be enough)

```
        function New-HTMLPage {
    
    $htmlexport = @"
            <!doctype html>
            <html lang="en">
            <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8">
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
                <title>Test</title>
            </head>
            <body>
            ...further HTML code blabla
    
    "@
    
    return $htmlexport
    
    }

$htmlexport = New-HTMLPage
$htmlexport | Out-File -FilePath "C:\Test.html"
```

Today i tried to implement a Side Navigationbar into my HTML Code. For this Navigation i used JavaScript in my HTML which i imported like so within the body tag:

```
<script src="assets/js/sidebar.js"></script>
```

This is how the Sidebar looks like without powershell:
[image]

But when i generate this HTML Page with my Powershell Script (like the example above) it looks completly shredded.
[image]

=> Now the interesting part is, that when i copy the generated Powershell HTML Output and paste it into a clean HTML file it looks perfectly fine (like the first picture). Nothing shredded ?!
So my conclusion is, that it is wether a general HTML syntax problem nor a issue in powershell.

Does anyone have an idea what i am missing out or maybe what i can try to solve the issue ?

P.S: If you require any further information please do not hesitate to ask. I have deliberately not included every detail here so there are not too much information.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Note that the leading whitespace before your HTML elements, notably before `<!doctype html>`,  is _included_ due to how you specify the contents of your [here-string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#here-strings)  (also, as shown, the code would break, because the closing delimiter isn't at the very start of the line).

Comment: Open HTML file with notepad.  Then from menu File: SaveAs. There is an encoding box in SaveAs.  Check the setting.  Compare the pasted version with the one saved with PS.

Comment: `Out-File` also has a parameter `-Encoding`

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I will check that tomorrow and you will get feedback.

Comment: @mklement0,@jdweng,@Theo
Absolutly fantastic, Thank you very much. The encoding solution did the Trick !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you very much to @mkelement,@jdweng,@Theo for providing this answer.

Finally the paramter -Encoding from the Out-File helped to sove the problem.
To find out the right encoding it followed the instructions from @Theo's comment.

Finally the correct CMDLet was:

Out-File -Encoding utf8 -FilePath "$Filepath"